# error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.android.justjava;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

1. throws error

   /**

   - This app displays an order form to order coffee.
     */
     public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     /**

     - This method is called when the order button is clicked.
       */
       public void submitOrder(View view) {
       display(1);
       }

     /**

     - This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
       */
       private void display(int number) {
       TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
       quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
       }
       }